# How to use webapi to get similar results like CSV Plugin

Tags: csv, asp.net-web-api, sonarqube

I'm using the (deprecated) CSV Plugin in SonarQube to create some analysis. Is there a way to get the same information by using the web api ?

"same information" means in my case:

FullClasspath | Metric 1 | Metric 2 | ... | Metric n 
----------------------------------------------------------
 org.myClass1 | Value 1 | Value 2 | ... | Value n
 org.myClass2 | Value 1 | Value 2 | ... | Value n
 org.myClass3 | Value 1 | Value 2 | ... | Value n

What I need is a combination of [getting all Metrics](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743272) and [receiving all "Classes"](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=231080558) instead of Issues.

I'd like to use SonarQube now and in the future. This is why I'd prefer to alter my setup to use the Web Api.

Best Regards

EDIT: Solution 
The request I have to send at my sonar server has this structure:

SERVER/api/resources?resource=COMPANY:PROJECT&depth=-1&metrics=ALLNEEDEDMETRICS

for example: [http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&depth=-1&metrics=ncloc,complexity,class_complexity,violations_density,duplicated_blocks,ca](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=org.codehaus.sonar%3asonar&depth=-1&metrics=ncloc,complexity,class_complexity,violations_density,duplicated_blocks,ca)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to the following "/api/resources" web service documentation : http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743280

Comment: I've seen this before and tried: SERVER/api/resources?resource=com.COMPANY:PROJECT&metrics=ncloc,function_complexity,lines.
First: this is just an overview / aggregation of all classes of this project. But I need the metric values detailed for every single class
Second: I would have to put every Metric (and I need all) in the URL which is kind of annoying (but possible)

I see an workaround. First get all Resources from "?resource=com.COMPANY:PROJECT&depth=-1
Then iterate over all resources with "&metrics=ncloc,function_complexity,lines,....,Metric N"
But this would be a pain ...

Comment: Concerning the first question @Tharmar, here is for instance the way to get the ncloc and complexity measures for all sources files contained in the SonarQube project on Nemo: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&depth=-1&scopes=FIL&metrics=ncloc,complexity

Comment: Thx @Freddy this combination works for me. I just have to put all metrics in the webapi-request ("kinf of annoying but possible").

Comment: the menitoned link is no longer available, could you help me with the updated link?